# Autocomplete web form with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, webforms

I've made a web form and i need some of the fields to come up with a dynamic list as the user is typing their input. the list needs to come from a separate table and fill in other corresponding fields if one of the options is taken. i know this is a very vague question but i'm new to ruby so if anyone can give me the easiest/simplest way to do this that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `easiest/simplest way to do this` is using the gem [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete). The documentation is very good, which facilitate its implementation.

Just follow the [instructions](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete#installing) and `voilà!`

Answer (score 2):

Create a route that outputs JSON. The controller for the route takes an input param (the user's input) and returns values from the database based on that. In the most recent one I did I used a JQuery autocomplete plugin to send the input from the field via ajax to that route and use the return value in the field's drop down.